# How to make only bold text in button when mouse hover?

Tags: css

I'd like to make the only bold text in button when the mouse hover.
In this case,

```
.button:hover {
   font-weight: bolder;
}
```

button and text are bold at the same time.

Comment: Post a [mcve] and please clarify your question, Wang.

Comment: for example.

<button class="btn btn-danger">Button</button>

button {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

Comment: What are you saying, that your CSS isn't being applied? Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: Show us your HTML mark up as well, so anyone can see the bigger picture of what are you working on with

Answer (score 4):

```
<button class="btn">
Click
</button>
```

To select an element by class use "." followed by "class name"

For class Selector:

```
.btn:hover {
   font-weight: bolder;
}
```

and if you want to add any css to an element/control then, use just the element

For element Selector:

```
button:hover {
   font-weight: bolder;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> Its not "bolder"

you have to write instead:

```
font-size: bold;
```

Comment: Yes, `bolder` is a perfectly valid value for the `font-weight` property. As are `normal`, `bold`, `lighter`, and numeric values. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: As much for me ^^’

Comment: I changed it to `bold`, but it's still same. 
You can see it, there is `bolder` property.

Comment: // Wrong comment, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.view:hover {
   font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
  <button class="view">view</button>
```

Comment: Guess you didn't take the time to read the other answer. Yes, `bolder` is a perfectly valid value for the font-weight property. As are `normal`, `bold`, `lighter`, and numeric values. Read developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Comment: What's there to check? It's still wrong. If `bolder` doesn't work for the OP, why would `bold`?

Comment: as you can see at the example, when you mouse hover to button, both of button and text are bold. I'd like to get only text, not button.

Answer (score -1):

**Try Using this Code**

```css
.button {
  /*assign width to get the text bolder inside that area*/
  width:90px;
}

.button:hover {
  font-weight:bolder;
  }
```

```html
<button class="button">Hover Me</button>
```